# JFrog xray not scanning gradle apk

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, devops, jfrog-xray

I am using JFrog Cloud Pro X (from AWS marketplace) to detect vulnerabilities/license issues in my setup. In one of my projects, I am using Gradle to build an android app, push it to Jfrog Artifactory and use Xray on that apk. Jenkins configuration looks like below for scan

```
def scan_conf = [
    'buildName'      : name,
    'buildNumber'    : number,
    'failBuild'      : true
  ]
  jfrogServer.xrayScan scan_conf
```

For maven based projects I am getting the proper result, but for Gradle one I am getting the below result:

```
{
  "summary" : {
    "message" : "Build xyz: number 26 was scanned by Xray and passed with no Alerts",
    "total_alerts" : 0,
    "fail_build" : false,
    "more_details_url" : "my_url"
  },
  "alerts" : [ ],
  "licenses" : [ ]
}
```

[image: Xray Data]
I want to understand that if the Jfrog is even scanning the apk or not, any help regarding his would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Xray does not support scanning app right now. List of supported packages can be found here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Xray

Comment: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-packages-and-repositories-are-supported-in-xray-for-indexing/
Then is it possible to scan the generic repository that has apk extension? As mentioned in the above link?